# Razor pages ef core - CRUD how to modify nested collection on Edit? DbConcurencyException

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor, entity-framework-core

In my project I use LazyLoading with EF Core, I have 2 entities:

```
    public class OfferEntity : BaseEntity
    {

        public string Category { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ImagePreviewEntity> ImagePreviews { get; set; }

    }

    public class ImagePreviewEntity: BaseEntity
    {

        public string PreviewUrl { get; set; }

    }
```

I can create them from my Create razor page this way (using js to dynamically add new rows):

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="OfferEntity.Category" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div id="ImagePreviews" class="form-group">
            <input id="addImageBtn" type="button" value="Add new">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.OfferEntity.ImagePreviews.Count; i++)
            {
                <input asp-for="OfferEntity.ImagePreviews[i].PreviewUrl" class="form-control" />
            }
        </div>
```

In standart Create.cshtml.cs I've only added 1'st entity creation for the binding model: `OfferEntity = new() { ImagePreviews = new() { new() } };`

And it works complete fine until it comes to EDIT. My edit razor page is same as Create.
My Edit.cshtml.cs:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
    {
        OfferEntity = await _context.Offers.Include(x => x.ImagePreviews).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();

        //await _context.Offers.Include(p => p.ImagePreviews).LoadAsync();

        var toRemove = OfferEntity.ImagePreviews
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PreviewUrl))
            .ToList();

        _context.Attach(OfferEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.ImagePreviews.RemoveRange(toRemove);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        return return RedirectToPage("./Index");
     }
```

There are 2 problems that I can't figure out:

1. ImagePreviews changes are not saved on the parent entity.
2. Removing empty ImagePreviews cause DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s).

What I've tried:

1. Injecting dbСontext from scopeFactory
2. Marking removed entities to State = Deleted
3. Loading dbSet with include(imagePreview) directly from context instead of attaching.
4. Removing entities from the OfferEntity.ImagePreviews collection
5. Dancing with a tambourine

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling one day with EF, came to non elegant but working solution.
Some of the problems were:

1. My new entities has no ID
2. My existing entities in the Edit razor page has no ID attached to them.
3. I was trying to attach nested properties multiple times.

Here is my OnPostAsync:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();

        var newImages = OfferEntity.ImagePreviews
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Id))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var imagePreviewEntity in newImages)
        {
            imagePreviewEntity.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            await _context.ImagePreviews.AddAsync(imagePreviewEntity);
        }

        _context.Attach(OfferEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;

        var relatedPreviewIds = OfferEntity.ImagePreviews.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
        var previews = await _context.ImagePreviews
            .Where(x => relatedPreviewIds.Contains(x.Id))
            .ToListAsync();

        previews.ForEach(entity =>
        {
            _context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(OfferEntity.ImagePreviews.First(p => p.Id == entity.Id));
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.PreviewUrl))
            {
                _context.Attach(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                return;
            }

            if (_context.Entry(entity).State != EntityState.Added)
                _context.Attach(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        });

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            if (!OfferEntityExists(OfferEntity.Id))
                return NotFound();

            throw;
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

I feel like there must be much cleaner solution for this. Its insane to write as much code to just add/remove entities from the nested list.